# Receive POST from External Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post, external

I have a form on another website (using a different backend) that I want to be able to POST to my Rails application (on a different domain).

- How do I generate a valid authenticity token for the external form so that my Rails app will accept it?
- Assuming I can do the answer to the above question--is there anything else special I need to do to make this work?  Apart from the authenticity token, the rest of it seems pretty straightforward to me...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't generate an autenticity token from outside your Rails app.
What you can do, is to [disable the token protection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#M000514) only for this action and use a custom implementation based on a before_filter.

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :my_action
before_filter :verify_custom_authenticity_token, :only => :my_action

def verify_custom_authenticity_token
  # checks whether the request comes from a trusted source
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just remove the check by adding a filter like:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :action_name
```

Comment: Doesn't this open me up to anyone posting to my rails app? Isn't this  a security concern?

Comment: You can add whatever other verification mechanism you want (ip address, whatever) in another filter, for example.