# Why does the post method seem to be clearing my rails session data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

After the user has logged in and their username authenticated and saved in session[:user_name], when submitting a form with method="post" (using standard html) all session data is cleared and user is routed back to the login page.  This does not happen if the method is set to get.

Post works when I use the rails "form_tag"  which generates these additional lines:

```
<div style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: inline;">
<input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
<input type="hidden" value="a_bunch_of_gibberish" name="authenticity_token">
</div>
```

What is happening?

Comment: Because different actions are executed. You should show your controller code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using Rails 3.0.4? It sounds like it might be related to the [CSRF fix](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails).

If you need a fix specific to your needs, you can overwrite #handle_unverified_request in your controller. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb.

[Here's an example](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/44) where this issue was with OmniAuth and OpenId. (See section 'CSRF Protection In Rails 3.0.4')

Comment: I am using 3.0.4 and after glancing at the "CSRF Protection Bypass in Ruby on Rails" article I think you are right:  'There are two major changes in this fix, the behaviour when CSRF protection fails has changed and the token will now be required for all non-GET requests.

After applying this patch failed CSRF requests will no longer generate HTTP 500 errors, instead the session will be reset.'

Comment: A simple explanation of how to overwrite the forgery handling: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1730421/216717

Answer (score 6):

This issue can also happen if you're creating your own html form.

If you're getting redirected without knowing why, it's because of "protect_from_forgery" in your ApplicationController

In order to allow your form to post, add the following code to it (or use `form_tag`, explanation below):

```
<form ... >
...
<%= hidden_field_tag "authenticity_token", form_authenticity_token %>
...
</form>
```

The reason the "form_tag" works is because `form_tag` generates the hidden field for you =)

Comment: @Dave glad it did! :-)