# Rails logs me out when I run a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

I have a site built using the railstutorial as a template. I have added a search controller to allow me to perform site searches and redirect the user to a search view. When I go to the path '/search' it is as expected (no results) but if I actually use the search input box I get logged out and have to log back in. What would be causing this?

My form:

```
<form action="/search" method="POST" class="navbar-search pull-right">
    <input name="query" type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

My search controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def index
        unless params[:query].nil?
            @results = ThinkingSphinx.search params[:query]
        else
            @results = []
        end
    end
end
```

My view:

```
<% unless @results.empty? %>
    <table class="table">
        <% @results.each do |result| %>
            <tr>
                <% if result.class.name == "Event" %>
                    <td><%= link_to result.name, organisation_event_path(result.organisation, result.slug) %></td>
                    <td><%= result.summary %></td>
                <% end %>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
<% else %>
    <p>No results found.</p>
<% end %>
```

My route:

```
match '/search', to: 'search#index'
```

Comment: I fixed this by changing the method to `get`. Why should this have any bearing on the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to CSRF issues. You can read the [details here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails/), or this [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082769/why-does-the-post-method-seem-to-be-clearing-my-rails-session-data).