# Rails 4: How to set cookies in redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

I have a controller that attempts takes form inputs, set values in a cookie and then redirect to a page that will pull from that cookie.

The problem is that the cookie is never set in the redirect headers.

*Notes:* I've tested in Chrome and FF.  Rails version is 4.0.13. Setting cookies w/o a redirect works as expected.

Here's the controller code:

```
def create
  request.cookies[:foo] = "bar"

  # also tried:
  #   cookies[:foo]="bar"
  #   cookies.signed[:foo]="bar"
  #   cookies[:foo] = {
  #     value: "bar",
  #     expires: 1.month.from_now,
  #     domain: ".myapplicationhostname.com"
  #   }

  redirect_to root_url
end
```

The response header on the redirect doesn't contain a Set-Cookie attribute and as such, the cookie values aren't available in the controller/action in the redirected-to path.

I've found some [contradictory evidence](http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/11/25/302-cookie.html) that some browsers don't accept cookies in redirects, but it appears that that's not the case anymore? And anyways, neither FF or Chrome are showing a `Set-Cookie` in the response header, so it doesn't appear this is a browser issue.

Here's the header response from cURL, note the lack of `Set-Cookie`:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
Location: http://app.mydomain.com:3000/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 1fc1c7e5-7489-4720-bb70-28588f3abcb6
X-Runtime: 4.688166
Connection: close
Server: thin 1.6.2 codename Doc Brown
```

**How do I get rails to set cookies (or at least set the header) on redirects?**

Comment: What is the issue with headers? `request.headers["foo"] = "bar"`

Comment: Are you redirecting to the same domain?

Comment: I'm trying to set cookies server-side and that's usually done by using the Set-Cookie http header.  Suppose I could try setting that header manually, but that seems hacky.

Comment: Ultimately I want to redirect to another subdomain so I know I have to set the domain to `.mydomain.com` on the cookie explicitly, but it doesn't even work when redirecting on the same domain as shown above.

Comment: I was trying to upgrade a Rails application from Rails 3.2 to 4.0, and came across this problem, and I couldn't find any mention of it in the upgrade guide. Thanks for writing this up!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that the cause of this is actually CSRF protection kicking in.  The controller had instantiated a `NullCookieJar` which prevents the writing of cookies when there's a potentially forged POST.

This is because my controller was being set up to respond to an off-site form, thus no access to the CSRF token.

So, if you're running into this when submitting an off-site form to your Rails app, you'll need to disable the CSRF check or write your own verification method as described in the answer to the SO question: ["Receive POST from External Form"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730377/receive-post-from-external-form).

Summarized here:

**Disabling Check**

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: :my_action
```

**Custom Check**

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :my_action
before_filter :verify_custom_authenticity_token, :only => :my_action

def verify_custom_authenticity_token
  # checks whether the request comes from a trusted source
end
```

Comment: It wouldn't access the CSRF even when you were attempting on the same domain?

Comment: I hadn't tried on the same domain. This was being built as a form widget meant for third party sites that would post to my application.